# Rename-SPServer and Hostname

Tags: administration, setup

For `Rename-SPServer`, MSDN says:

> The Rename-SPServer cmdlet changes the name of the server for
>   internal use within SharePoint Products. The server itself must be
>   manually renamed.

Now the last part isn't clear. Is renaming of the physical box (hostname/netbios name) optional or mandatory for SharePoint farm to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Renaming a server is a 2 step process. First you physically change the host name of the server, then you run the Rename-SPServer Cmdlet to update SharePoint farm configuration to recognize the new server name.

Yes, changing the physical host name is required. You only need to run the Rename-SPServer CmdLet when the physical host name of a server changes after it has already been added to a SharePoint Farm. In a multi-server farm, the alternative is to remove the server from the farm, change the host name, then re-add the server back into the farm like adding a new server.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris mentioned renaming SharePoint Server is a 2-step process. I came across a similar situation where I have to rename a SharePoint Application server and Web-front server. I first changed the machine name physically and then used stsadm rename server command. I found lot of articles that mention that *never* use Rename-SPServer command as you could run in to various issues.

Some useful links below:-

> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607556.aspx - Rename-SPServer Microsoft article
>   http://www.topsharepoint.com/rename-sharepoint-2010-server
>   http://aanikin.wordpress.com/2010/09/01/how-to-rename-sharepoint-2010-server/
>   http://joelblogs.co.uk/2011/10/23/renaming-a-standalone-sharepoint-2010-server/
>   http://www.zomgrei.com/blog/tech/renaming-a-standalone-sharepoint-2010-server/ -- good one.
>   http://vijaynats.blogspot.com.au/2011/04/renaming-sharepoint-2010-server.html
>   http://blog.walisystemsinc.com/2012/08/how-to-change-sharepoint-2010-server.html
>   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/ae73d73e-a8cf-44f6-ae4a-fd89dd5f543b
>   http://www.ericjochens.com/2013/03/change-sharepoint-server-hostname-and.html
>   http://www.askaboutasp.net/_-_78_How_to_rename_a_SharePoint_Server_machine_name_3f.aspx
>   http://code-journey.com/2009/clone-sharepoint-moss-wss-stand-alone-developer-virtual-machine-rename-sharepoint-server/