# About renaming Frontend and App server

Tags: rename

I have to rename the front server and app server in a Sharepoint 2013 farm.
I've already renamed the DB Server.

It's not clear if I should rename the hostnmame first and then run 
Rename-SpSever or viceversa.

According to two users [in this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72411/rename-spserver-and-hostname), the hostname should be renamed first.

But then on other articles is the other way round:

[article 1](http://vijaynats.blogspot.it/2011/04/renaming-sharepoint-2010-server.html)
[article 2](http://www.askaboutasp.net/_-_78_How_to_rename_a_SharePoint_Server_machine_name_3f.aspx)

So which first Rename-SpSever (or stsadm) or the hostname?

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't matter in which order you do it as long as you do those after each other to minimize possible downtime.

I'd personally perhaps first rename host, then do rename-spserver as it would seem better from SharePoint's perspective: first host name change just causes SP not to find the server (which is essentially the case whenever you restart that host) so shouldn't be a biggie.

But in the end it shouldn't make any difference.